# Unable to locate optgroup or select tag with capybara

Tags: xpath, rspec, capybara

I get the following HTML-Structur with Capybara (puts body.page)

```
    <div class="analyze-select" id="select-project">
      <label class="label" for="project_id_Select Project">Select project</label>
<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Project" id="select_project_id" name="select[project_id]" style="width: 150px; display: none;">
      <option value=""></option>
      <optgroup label="Active">
        <option value="1">Project-0</option>
        <option value="2">Project-1</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Inactive">
        <option value="6">deactivated project 3</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
```

When I try

```
page.should have_xpath("//div[@id='select-project']") # => true
page.should have_xpath("//label[@for='project_id_Select Project']") # => true 
page.should have_xpath("//select[@class='chosen-select']") # => false
page.should have_xpath("//optgroup") # => false
```

Why can't the select- or optgroup-tag be found?

Comment: `//optgroup[contains(@label,'Active')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For select you can use have_select node matcher with visible option. "false" will check for both visible and invisible elements in the page.

page.should have_select("id/name/label", visible: false)

Answer (score 0):

For hidden selected value:

`expect(page).to have_select('id/name/label', selected: 'OPTION_TEXT', visible: false)`

Thanks @sohini-chandra.